# Uploaded file does not show in S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 using multipart upload with TransferConfig:
Every thing seems okay as the program runs without errors:

```
import threading,boto3,re,os,sys
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

#create resource
s3=boto3.resource('s3',
              region_name = region,
              aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
              aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
              aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN)

BUCKET_NAME="my_bucket"

# the upload function
def multi_part_upload_with_s3():
    # Multipart upload
    config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024*25, max_concurrency=10000, 
                        multipart_chunksize=1024*25, use_threads=True)
    #file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/largefile.pdf'
    file_path = "C:/Users/Documents/MyFile.out"
    key_path = 'MyDir/MySubDir/'    
    s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_path, BUCKET_NAME, key_path, 
                               #ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read', 'ContentType': 
                               'text/pdf'},
                               Config=config, Callback=ProgressPercentage(file_path))

#Not really important, just tells you what percentage of your file has uploaded.
class ProgressPercentage(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        self._size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
        self._seen_so_far = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        
    def __call__(self, bytes_amount):
        with self._lock:
            self._seen_so_far += bytes_amount
            percentage = (self._seen_so_far/self._size)*100
            sys.stdout.write("\r%s %s/%s (%.2f%%)" % (self._filename, 
                             self._seen_so_far, self._size, percentage))
        sys.stdout.flush()

#Now call fucntion
if __name__=='__main__':
    multi_part_upload_with_s3()
```

Output:

```
C:/Users/Documents/MyFile.out 1295607/1295607.0 (100.00%)
```

So it appears to run without errors. However, when I look in S3, 'MySubDir' is created, but 'MyFile.out' is not in there. I thought maybe having the max concurrency in S3 was the culprit thinking it would take a while to join it back up, but I've waited for over 4 hours and nothing has shown up. I've also used other files and other uploading approaches and files would show up in 'MySubDir'.

Answer (score 2):

You never specify the destination file name, only the path.  Try:

```
file_path = "C:/Users/Documents/MyFile.out"
key_path = 'MyDir/MySubDir/MyFile.out'    
s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_path, BUCKET_NAME, key_path, 
                           #ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read', 'ContentType': 
                           'text/pdf'},
                            Config=config,Callback=ProgressPercentage(file_path))
```

Comment: OMG, what an oversight. Whole day gone, but will save days, mabe a week, on uploading 4TB of files. Much appreciated.